# how to have a unique calendar entity for each user entity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design, rails-activerecord

I am writing an application which will extensively use calendar for storing the daily information on various things, for each entity. Now how do I make a new calendar for each entity. Do I make a table for each entry in the user table?

### Edit:

I am having an entity user.
Now for each entity there is a calendar for the whole year. for each day in the year there are 2 fields which will have some data.

now how do i make that? should i create a new table for each user? or should i just use foreign key of the user and have 365 entries in the calendar table for each user.

### Edit:

Each user will only have one event each day.
also since the events occur on some item of the user, and the user has many items, so one user can have multiple calendars.

Comment: A user can have more than 365 events, you have multiple events per day. On my calendar I have hundreds of entries per month, not all need my attendance, some are just milestone reminders. I would not limit the number of events a user can have.

Comment: one user is bound to have at the max one event per day in the calendar(I have edited my quetion). The solution you gave is pretty straightforward, although it may happen there will be an event every day, but the chances of it are very slim. Thanks for the answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have one table for Users and one table for Calendar. This is what I would start with:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :calendar_events
end

class CalendarEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Then you can do:

```
User.calendar.calendar_events #returns array of active record CalendarEvent objects
User.calendar.calendar_events.where(:start_date => Date.today) #assuming you have a start date field
```

These models will only be a bonafide calendar when you render the events in a grid that looks like a calendar.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I think tester123 has a good answer to your question.

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :calendar
  has_many :calendar_events, :through => :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :calendar_events
end

class CalendarEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

In this case you have a table `users` and each user has its own calendar entry in table `calendars`. A user can also have 0 or more `calendar_events`. A calendar event has a column `event_date` (the day of the year you're talking about) and the two fields which have 'some data'.

Comment: I know this, what I am asking is that, for each day in calendar there will be some data to be put in front of it.How do i achieve that

Comment: What kind of data and where do you want it to be put in front of? Again: please try to be more specific.